# Passing variables between windows using window.opener in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, window.open, window.opener

I have two windows; one of them is opened using the function `window.open("URL", [parameters])`. My problem is that I want to send elements from the child window to the parent window, and this works ok in all browsers, except in Internet Explorer (currently using IE11).

I want to find out a solution because it needs to work on Internet Explorer.

The code I use is written in jQuery, as i show below:

```
//Inicializating document and events
var x=$(document);
x.ready(inicializarDocumento);

function inicializarDocumento(){
    var x=$("#boAceptar");
//When i click in my button it executes the function pasarDatos
    x.click(pasarDatos);
}

function pasarDatos(){
//I get the reference of the windows father
    var doc=window.opener.document;
    var x=window.opener.$("#seleccionDireccionId");


    var form=$("form[name='foconfirmar']");


//I execute the next code when i submit the form
    form.submit(function (event){
        var listadoid=$("#listadoid option:selected");
        var tipoVia=$("#idTipoVia");
        var km=$("#idkm");
        var piso=$("#idPiso");
        var puerta=$("#idPuerta");
        var urbanizacion=$("#idUrbanizacion");
        var bloque=$("#idBloque");
        var escalera=$("#idEscalera");
        var observaciones=$("#idObservaciones");


        if (listadoid.text()==""){
            alert("Debe seleccionar una dirección de las disponibles");

        }else{
            var o = new Option(listadoid.text()+", "+tipoVia.val()+", "+km.val()+", "+piso.val()+", "+puerta.val()+", "+urbanizacion.val()+", "+bloque.val()+", "+escalera.val()+", "+observaciones.val(), listadoid.val());

            $(o).html(listadoid.text()+", "+tipoVia.val()+", "+km.val()+", "+piso.val()+", "+puerta.val()+", "+urbanizacion.val()+", "+bloque.val()+", "+escalera.val()+", "+observaciones.val());

            x.append(o);
        }
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });
    self.close();
}
```

Comment: When you say "doesn't work", exactly what happens?  Are there errors shown in the debug console?

Comment: Rather than this `var x=window.opener.$("#seleccionDireccionId");`, I'd suggest trying this: `var x=$("#seleccionDireccionId", doc);`

Comment: i have just been doing a debugging to my code and first gives me a SyntaxError in the line "x.append(o)" and after that it gives me another error which says "exception not controled", and i guess that the second error is just a consecuence of the first one. I have to say that i also have tried your suggestion but still the same, but thx

Comment: My guess is that you can't use jQuery methods that create DOM elements when the you are in the context of the wrong document for that content because jQuery will create the content for the wrong document (internally using `document.createElement()`) with the wrong `document` object.